# Cannot run Gracenote MusicId Demo in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, gracenote

I just downloaded the GNSDK for iOS (gn-mobile-ios-1.2.1.4576) and cannot get the demo app to run in the emulator.

Here's the error I am getting:

```
GracenoteMusicId[49126:28681347] Unknown class _TtC16GracenoteMusicId21GnViewControllerSwift in Interface Builder file.
```

I am running Xcode 8.2.1 and trying to run on an emulator of iPhone 7 Plus.

I upgraded the project to Xcode 8, and that compiled without issue, but I get this error both before and upgrading the project to Xcode 8.

Comment: I did some further investigation and found this error only occurs when using `GnViewControllerSwift` as the ViewController (Swift). When I use `GnViewController` (Obj-C), I do not get this error. Might be an issue with the Swift code, but at least I have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Either a storyboard or nib has an object in it with a custom class set to a class in the Gracenote library, however that library is not being linked into the final binary.  You need to make sure the library is being linked correctly.